# How do I know a View moved?

Tags: swt, rcp, jface, workbench

Is there a thing , like listener , knowing of a view is moved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that view is your try to use

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent){
    parent.getParent().addControlListener(new ControlAdapter(){
        public void controlMoved(ControlEvent e) {}
    });
}
```

If it is built-in view

```
WorkbenchPartReference ref = (WorkbenchPartReference) UIPlugin.getDefault().getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findViewReference("viewID");
    Control control = ref.getPane().getControl();
    control.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void controlMoved(ControlEvent e) {

        }
    });
```